# java -version showing old jdk 1.6 version

Tags: java

I have installed java 1.7 and updated java_home to points java 1.7 but if I check it from windows cmd `c://user//somefolder` and type java -version it shows old one not 1.7

Comment: Check the environmental variable PATH in your system.

Comment: Update `%PATH%` or `%JAVA_HOME%`, wherever appropriate.

Comment: Did you install Java 1.7 using the actual installer or by just downloading and unzipping the ZIP version?

Answer (score 4):

Check your `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables, are they correct?

(go in `cmd` and type `set` to see...)

PS. restart your windows command prompt if you had it open from before you updated to 1.7

Answer (score 1):

You are checking `JAVA_HOME`, but when you execute java.exe -version, the java.exe file is looked up in `PATH` variable. Most of the times `PATH` contains something like `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`, but in your case it might just point explicitly to the old JDK like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0`

- Make sure that `JAVA_HOME` points to, say, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0`
- Make sure that `PATH` begins with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`